# API must be enabled for service account project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

We have an issue with a service account 'defaulting' to the project where it was created when enabling APIs before creating resources.

The SA was created under project A but it has `Owner` rights for project B.

We're trying to create a resource (GKE cluster) in **project B** but it's complaining we need to enable the Kubernetes API on **project A** first (we are passing `--project` to the cluster create command to avoid any ambiguity around where we're trying to create the cluster. this is also the case for the get-credentials command).

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Kubernetes Engine API has not been used in project PROJECT_NUMBER before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview?project=PROJECT_NUMBER then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

`PROJECT_NUMBER` here is the number of project A, not B. The required API is already enabled on project B.

Is there something flawed in our approach to the use of service accounts here?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're creating a cluster in project B, the caller of the API is project A (because the service account is owned by project A); therefore, the API must be enabled on project A.

Comment: In this case the service account is being used as an identity. Therefore requiring project A to enable this API does not seem like a correct IAM design decision (by GCP). IAM should should only require Project B to have the API enabled. This would pose a problem for third party integrations also.

Comment: Indeed, if this is the case I've been wrong on my understanding of GCP service accounts for some time. @rob-kochman, do you happen to know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: I've spent quite a while looking through the docs, this is the best I've found: `Also make sure that the desired API(s) are enabled for the project that those credentials are associated with.` via: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#CustomCreds

The fact that this is so hard to find has me wondering if we're managing service accounts correctly. We have one which is owner over a number of projects for different environments. This perhaps isn't best practice!

Comment: I agree this is confusing. API enablement and IAM are separate, though. I'll look into improving the documentation.

Comment: I filed a documentation issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324314554